# Application of Noether-Lefschetz theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $f=f(T) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y][T]$ be a monic polynomial:
$f=T^n+a_{n-1}T^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1T+a_0$,
$a_j \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
Denote: $A=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $B=\mathbb{C}[x,y,T]/(f)=\mathbb{C}[x,y][w]$,
where $w^n+a_{n-1}w^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1w+a_0=0$.

If I am not wrong, the following claim is mentioned in the comments to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271662/for-which-f-in-mathbbcx-yt-all-irreducible-elements-of-mathbbcx) question:

**Claim:** If $n \geq 4$, then $B$ is a UFD for 'sufficiently general $f$'.

> **Question 1:** Could one please describle those 'sufficiently general $f$'s'?
>
> **Question 2:** What if $f$ is not monic?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I believe that it amounts to choose the coefficients "random". The best way to understand the precise meaning is by reading the proof. If $f$ is not monic, you can multiply by the reciprocal of $a_n$ to obtain a monic polynomial.

Comment: @Youngsu, thank you. Please, could you elaborate about the coefficients? Give examples?

Comment: @Youngsu, if $f=a_nT^n+a_{n-1}T^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1T+a_0$, then $\tilde{f}=T^n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}T^{n-1}+\cdots+\frac{a_1}{a_n}T+\frac{a_0}{a_n}$ (probably) has coefficiens in $k(x,y)$ not in $k[x,y]$; is this ok?

Comment: The set of monic polynomials as above are parametrized by affine spaces, given by $(a_0,\ldots, a_{n-1})$ by bonding the degrees of the $a_i$s. NL would say (it is an existence result, no explicit construction is claimed) that there exists a countable union of proper closed subsets of this affine space outside which you get a UFD if $n\geq 4$.

Comment: @Mohan, thank you very much.

Comment: @Mohan, unfortunately, I still do not understand the case $a_n \in k[x,y]-k$. We have $(a_0,\dots,a_{n-1},a_n)$ (perhaps the same result holds if $n \geq3$? or I am completely wrong).

Comment: If $a_n$ is not $1$, then play the same game with $b_i = a_i/a_n \in k$.

Comment: @Youngsu, $b_i=a_i/a_n \in k(x,y)$, is this ok?

Comment: That's correct since $k \subset k[x,y] \subset k(x,y)$. But a field is closed under division, too.